# Calculating the norm of each row in a matrix

Tags: matlab, math, matrix, norm

I have a Nx3 matrix (A)  the columns are X,Y,Z respectively. I want to calculate the norm that is sqrt(X^2+Y^2+Z^2) for each row. I did a for loop for that:

```
for i = 1:length(A)
Result(i) = norm(A(i,:))
end
```

is there any other way to do it avoiding for loop?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
sqrt(sum(A.^2, 2))
```

Your method returns a 1x3 where this returns a 3x1. So if you want you can transpose it but I doubt you really need to.

Comment: Actually I want it 3x1 as you did and in my method I prepare a column vector before the for loop. Thanks